# Angular 5: ngModel binding on select element doesn't update

Tags: html, angular, html-select

I have this markup for a select element:

```
<select type="submit" ([ngModel])="selectedValue" #item (change)="onSelectItem(item.value)">
                <option>Pick an option</option>
                <option *ngFor="let object of objects">{{ object.value }}</option>
</select>
```

When I update the ngModel binding from typescript, nothing happens. Essentially I am just doing this, in the component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.selectedValue = 'something' // One of the options from the list of objects
}
```

However, nothing happens.
The value I am trying to update it to, are in the list of objects (in the *ngFor) - if that matters.

Comment: check out my edit with some more information about `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `([ngModel])="selectedValue"` to `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"`

Just like the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---) say:

> Visualize a banana in a box to remember that the parentheses go inside the brackets.

Also you do not need the `(change)` listener if you are using `ngModel`. You can split your two way binding into `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <select type="submit" [ngModel]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="onSelectedChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let option of options">{{ option }}</option>
  </select>

  {{ selectedValue }}
  ` ,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedValue = 1;
  options = [1,2,3]

  onSelectedChange(value: number) {
    // do something else with the value
    console.log(value);

    // remember to update the selectedValue
    this.selectedValue = value;
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhptrd)

Comment: Use Template reference variable  instead of  passing entire event ,[Passing `$event` is a dubious practice](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#passing-event-is-a-dubious-practice)

Comment: In this case `$event` is an Angular Event. Not a DOM event. It is just a number. So your link does not apply. It is no different than any other event emitted by the `@Output` decorator.

Comment: thanx for the info :)

Comment: Also, remember to import the `FormsModule` into your module so you can use the `[(ngModel)]` directive.

Answer (score 0):

> Please change the definition of `([ngModel])` to `[(ngModel)]` and you should initialize the `objects` values before assign the value in `selectedValue` object

Comment: How is it different from other answer?

Comment: It's not, he just copied it.